# How to traverse a 3-level array for a specific keyword in PHP

Tags: php

I have a 3 level array. I want to display the value of a particular keyword. This keyword appears in both the 2nd level and the 3rd level. But i want to display just the 2nd level.

Any idea how to do this? I have tried the following but it is displaying out all the values of the key "name".

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($call_result, TRUE)),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
            
            if(strcmp ( $key , "name") == 0)
            {
                 //echo '<br>';
                 if(strcmp($val , " ")== 1)
                 {
                    echo "$key => $val\n";
                 }
                 
            }
}
```

Any idea, how to just print out the value of the 2nd level only?

Comment: Exactly what you want to display ?? The key of the element present in 3-level array. ? Show me ur array..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) 
    {
        foreach($value as $key => $value)
           
          {
                  if(strcmp( $key , "name") == 1)
                      {
             
                         if(strcmp($val , "name") == 1)
                         {
                            echo "$key\n";
                         }

                     }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($va as $k => $v){
                    
    foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
                        
            if(strcmp($k1 , "name") == 0)
            {
              echo "$k1 => $v1\n";
            }
                        
    }
                    
}
```